# reversing using ^= in C++

Tags: reverse, xor

i play around with reversing string the

```
std::string simpleReverse(std::string inputX) {
//std::string inputX;
std::cout << "Enter a word for revesrse" << std::endl;
std::cout << "You have entered '" << inputX << "'...\nResult is:";

std::string resultA = inputX;

for (int i=inputX.length()-1, j = 0; i>=0, j<5; i--, j++){
    //std::cout << inputX[i] << std::endl;
    resultA[j] = inputX[i];
}
inputX = resultA;
std::cout << resultA;
```

it work just fine, but i saw another method is

```
string FirstReverse(string str) { 
for(int i=0,j=str.length()-1;i<str.length()/2;i++,j--){
    str[i]^=str[j]^=str[i]^=str[j];
    }
return str; 
}
```

this work well with shortest code, but i don't understand how it work, i search a lot what is ^= but did't get answer what i want, how it work?

Comment: The `^`is the bitwise XOR operator, and it can be combined to swap values. While this works, it is bad code because it is very difficult to read by humans. Other options, like `std::swap()` are preferable.

Answer (score 1):

To swap two values `a` and `b`, we can write:

```
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm for more information.

That code is exactly this algorithm, but written in one line. First:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Then compact more. Note that `a ^= b` returns the new `a`, which instead of `b ^= a`, enables us to write `b ^= a ^= b`.

Answer (score 0):

^ means bitwise XOR
What it does is it retains only those bits at the same postion where the bit is different for both the variables.

e.g             'a' = 100000**1** 
                      'b' = 10000**1**0
a^b would be 00000**11**

Now that you bits that are different, when you ^ any of the two 'a' or 'b' it will give you the other as result.

i.e          'a' = 100000**1**
         'a'^'b' = 00000**11**
                     10000**1**0 //gives you 'b'

The common bits would come from 'a' and 'a's different bits will change to 0, thereby only 'b's different bits will remain.Hence giving you 'b'.

```
str[i]^=str[j]^=str[i]^=str[j];
```

To simplify this:

```
str[i]^=str[j]; expands to str[i]=str[i]^str[j]; //'a'^'b'
```

Next step:

```
str[j]^=str[i]^=str[j]; expands to str[j]=('a'^'b')^'b'//str[j]=str[i] which is 'a' in our case
```

And finally

```
str[i]^=str[j]^=str[i]^=str[j]; //'a'^('a'^'b')//str[i]=str[j] which is 'b' in our case
```

So they are swapped.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for explain , 
so simple explain is 1+2=3, 3-2=1, 3-1=2;

so the first swap is seem like unused;

Comment: Yes, but ^ is bit operator so it does everything at bit level.

Comment: If you read my explanation, you will realise it is quite intriguing:)

Comment: can you give me an example when this operator is useful?

Comment: i quite suprise the value can be swap with bit , gonna learn more how to use it wisely

Comment: You can read this article https://hackernoon.com/xor-the-magical-bit-wise-operator-24d3012ed821

Comment: Did you understand the explanation I gave?

Comment: ya i write the bit of ascii on paper and xor it each step, everything clear, i just curious when should i use this

Comment: You can use it swap nos.

Comment: i try with string but give me error, so it only swap num for use?

Comment: You can swap char inside the string, not the entire string

Comment: If you want to swap string you can do it with for-loop at char level